# SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client

Tags: php, sql

I'm sorry if this question ever asked before. However, I'm getting frustrate about this stuff.
Currently I'm maintenance a project, I'm using WampServer 2.0, PHP 5.2.5 and SQL Server 2005. 
I've added extension=php_sqlsrv_52_ts_vc6.dll inside php.ini copy the file to php's extension. However sqlsrv_connect() in the project didn't work. I read the manual book of the project, I have to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Client Native since this project was developed by other programmer few times ago using wampserver 2.0 and SQL Server 2008. In other word, the prerequisites: - Install Driver SQLSRV20,  SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client. But, I still confuse what's SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client used for. Do I need to install it though I use SQL Server 2005?

Please help. 
Thank in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do. Explained more fully [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Do I have to install Windows Server 2008 R2 though I use SQL Server 2005?
Why not Windows Server 2005 R2, is it exists?

Comment: You definitely don't need to install Windows Server :-) Yes, I doubt the 2005 version exists any more. The 2008 clients (e.g. Management Studio) are generally backwards compatible with 2005.